# How to copy custom images in Azure from one subscription to another

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli

I am running my virtual machines on Azure which consists of multiple directories and each directory has two-three subscriptions in it. I made a custom image for my infrastructure environment under my default subscription (say "Visual Studio Enterprise: BizSpark").

**I want to copy this custom image to other subscriptions under different directories so that this image is easily accessible throughout my Azure account.**

I was following this link : [Copy Managed Images by Michael S. Collier](https://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/copy-managed-images/)
but I got stuck at this snippet:

```
diskName=$(az vm show --resource-group linux -n vm --query "storageProfile.osDisk.name" -o tsv)
```

**Error:**

```
The Resource 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm' under resource group 'linux' was not found.
```

Any lead on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a managed disk or managed image, you can not directly move it from one subscription to another subscription which is existed in **a different tenant**. The error may indicate that you have connected to a different tenant.

If the original managed disk exists, you could refer this blog to [move Azure Managed Disk between Tenants](https://www.thomas-zuehlke.de/2018/02/moving-azure-managed-disk-between-tenants/)

> You can create a snapshot of the managed disk and move it to a storage
>   account in the source subscription, then copy the snapshot to a
>   storage account in the destination subscription and create a managed
>   disk out of the snapshot and a VM with the managed disk afterward.
>   Here are the main steps in PowerShell.

**A: Download the disk snapshot to a storage account**

```
$sourceSubscriptionId = ''
$sourceStorageAccountName = "SourceStorageAccount"
$sourceStorageAccountKey = "9O1...Kg=="
$sourceStorageAccountContainer = "containername"
# path of the download URL of the snapshot
$VHDDownloadUri = "https://....blob.core.windows.net/..."
$targetSnapshotName = "snapshot.vhd"
#download snapshot to StorageAccount-Source (the storage account is located in the source subscription)
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $sourceSubscriptionId
$sourceStorageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $sourceStorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $sourceStorageAccountKey
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $VHDDownloadUri -DestContainer $sourceStorageAccountContainer -DestContext $sourceStorageAccountContext -DestBlob $targetSnapshotName
```

**B: Copy the snapshot to a storage account in the destination subscription of an other tenant:**

```
$destSubscriptionId = ''
$destStorageAccount = "DestStorageAccount"
$destStorageAccountKey = "Pqn.../Q=="
$destStorageAccountContainer = "container"
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $destSubscriptionId
$destStorageAccountContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $destStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $destStorageAccountKey
Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Context $destStorageAccountContext -Blob $targetSnapshotName
$blobCopy = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -DestContainer $destStorageAccountContainer -DestContext $destStorageAccountContext -SrcBlob $targetSnapshotName -Context $sourceStorageAccountContext -SrcContainer $sourceStorageAccountContainer
Write-Host ($blobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState).CopyId
Write-Host ($blobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState).TotalBytes
Write-Host ($blobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState).BytesCopied
while(($blobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState).Status -eq "Pending")
{
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    #$blobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState
    $output = "`r" + ($blobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState).BytesCopied
    Write-Host $output -NoNewline
}
The copy process runs asynchronous. If you need to stop the copy process, get the CopyId and use the Stop-AzureStorageBlogCopy command: Stop-AzureStorageBlobCopy -Container $destStorageAccountContainer -Blob $targetSnapshotName -CopyId "<GUID>" -Context $destStorageAccountContext
```

**C: Create a new VM and use the snapshot.vhd from the DestStorageAccount as base image for the managed disk:**

```
$rgName = "DestResourceGroup"
$location = "northeurope"
$storageName = "MyVMstorage"
$storageType = "Standard_LRS"
$nicname = "MyVM-nic"
$subnet1Name = "MyVM-subnet"
$vnetName = "MyVM-vnet"
$vnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"
$vnetSubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"
$vmName = "MyVM"
$vmSize = "Standard_D2s_v3"
$osDiskName = $vmName + "osDisk"
$osDiskUri = "https://deststorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/snapshot.vhd"
$storageacc = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $storageName -Type $storageType -Location $location
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $nicname -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$subnetconfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnet1Name -AddressPrefix $vnetSubnetAddressPrefix
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -AddressPrefix $vnetAddressPrefix -Subnet $subnetconfig
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicname -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
$discStorageAcc = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $destStorageAccount
$diskConfig = New-AzureRmDiskConfig -AccountType 'PremiumLRS' -Location $location -CreateOption Import -StorageAccountId ($discStorageAcc.Id) -SourceUri $osDiskUri
$disk = New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -ResourceGroupName $rgName -DiskName "managedsnapshot"
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -ManagedDiskId $disk.Id -CreateOption Attach -Windows
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm -Verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

first command just retrieves disk name, so if you know disk name you dont have to run it. just do:

```
diskName="diskname_goes_here"
```